# What was the image Dr. Juliet Burke carved in a tree in season three?

Tags: lost, influences, easter-egg

When Dr. Juliet Burke was sent to the camp of survivors on the beach by Ben, she carved an image on a tree as a sign for him.

What was that image?

The reason I ask is that the image could indicate a hint, an "Easter egg" put there by the author (J.J.Abrams?) to some other influencing work. I have an idea, but I'd like a confirmation on the image first.

**update:** So, to clarify. To me, that looks just like a "stylized Cyrillic Zhe" (Ж) symbol, with the associated connotations of hinting at the Strugatsky brothers' "Beetle in the anthill" - where such a symbol on an external device as well as on a subject's body was prominently featured. I take it as the hint that JJ is a fan of theirs. Their creation is really high grade.

Another hint at the cross-influence is the giant, dangerous, extremely fast-moving arachnid with hands in the "Super 8" 2011 film by JJ (though in Strugatsky's *Noon universe* those weren't intelligent).

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the image or confirm which episode it was in?

Comment: Is this what you're referring to? http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Tree_mark

Comment: @Richard yes!! thanks a bunch! I should sharpen my search skills ... a lot. :) To me, that looks just like a "stylized Cyrillic Zhe" (Ж) symbol, with the associated connotations of hinting at the Strugatsky brothers' "Beetle in the anthill" - where such a symbol on an external device *as well as* on a subject's body was prominently featured. Maybe JJ is a fan of theirs? Their creation is really high grade. -- so, would you post the answer so I could accept it?

Comment: It can/should be noted that JJ Abrams had almost nothing to do with the show after the initial episode. He helped create the show and was heavily involved in the show's bible, but had almost nothing to do with specific storylines or plot points past the pilot of the show.

Comment: @phantom42 the bible is what matters, if we're thinking of easter eggs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image you're referring to is generally called (by fans of the show) the "Tree Mark". You can read some additional info about it on the Lostpedia [here](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Tree_mark).

[image]

Given that the show has repeatedly referenced other alchemical symbols (Juliet has [the symbol for Spirit](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Juliet%27s_mark) branded on her neck) it seems most likely that it's at least inspired by the historic notation for Ammionium Salt, otherwise known as [Sal Ammoniacus](http://www.symbols.com/symbol/2334))

[image]

Comment: thanks; I'm holding on to my interpretation though, given other (perceived) hints at the crossinfluence that I mention - like the giant, dangerous, extremely fast-moving arachnoid with hands in the "Super 8" 2011 film by JJ (though in the Strugatsky's Noon universe those weren't intelligent).

Comment: I see a very slim lobster facing towards me with his claws outstretched.

Comment: was that really a constructive remark? it didn't feel like it, to me.

Comment: @darveter - constructive is a very subjective term. Given the kind of muddled nonsense that Lost ended up becoming, it's at least as likely as any other guess :-)))

Comment: couldn't agree more, about your characterization of Lost.